# Uploading Video to video Library using SharePoint2013 Rest APIs

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest, video

I am using SharePoint RestAPIs to upload video to Video Library using the following urls and the video is uploaded successfully:

1. _api/web/lists/getbytitle('Video Library')/rootfolder/Files/add(url='a.mp4')
2. _api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Video Library')/Files/add(url='a.mp4')

The issue is that the AJAX calling are return in the error method(file not found) not in the success method and I want to use the file url after uploading

Note the following:

1. when you upload a video to video library SharePoint create a folder with the name of the uploaded video file name and put the video file inside it.
2. If you already uploaded a file with the same name SharePoint create the folder with random name and put the video inside it.

Comment: Having the same issue - my url had “overwrite=true” parameter in the url and it still did not overwrite the existing file, just appended a random string to the end.